# How to move the selected radio button to left side

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What i am trying to achieve is that when someone clicks a radio button the button moves to the left by hiding other radio button thereby creating a foldable like effect.

I tried this with css float:left property and its moving but can see a rectangle only. Here is my code

Html

```
<form>
  <group class="inline-radio">
    <div>
      <input id="opt1" type="radio" name="title">
      <label>opt1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="opt2" type="radio" name="title">
      <label>opt2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="opt3" type="radio" name="title">
      <label>opt3</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="opt4" type="radio" name="title">
      <label>opt4</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="opt5" type="radio" name="title">
      <label>others</label>
    </div>
  </group>

</form>
```

javascript

```
//for toggling  
var hid = false;

$("group.inline-radio").click(function() {
  if (hid == false) {

    $('group.inline-radio').find('input[type="radio"]').not(':checked').hide().siblings('label').hide();

    hid = true;
    return;
  } else {
    $('group.inline-radio').find('input[type="radio"]').not(':checked').show().siblings('label').show();

    hid = false;
  }

});
```

Here is the code in codepen http://codepen.io/flyingboy007/pen/ojoVWe

Comment: That is because you would need to hide the `div` container not the label. Although i am still a bit unclear as to what you would like your desired effect to be

Comment: Agreed with @Adjit: the desired behavior is not clear.

Comment: @Adjit.Sorry that its not clear..What i am looking for is a foldable like effect.(for eg: If someone clicks on the 3rd radiobutton it will hide all other radiobutton and move to the place of the first one ). I will update the question with this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the div selector in your css to this:

```
div {
position: relative;
width: 20%;
float:left;
}
```

And change your javascript to this:

```
var hid = false;

$("group.inline-radio").click(function() {
  if (hid == false) {

    $('group.inline-radio').find('input[type="radio"]').not(':checked').parent().hide();

    hid = true;
    return;
  } else {
     $('group.inline-radio').find('input[type="radio"]').not(':checked').parent().show();

     hid = false;
   }

});
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojpNVq

Comment: Is this what you were trying to accomplish?

Comment: How can i show a text regarding the choosen radio button and is  it possible to extend the last radiobutton to a dropdown with more lists?

Comment: A different text for each radio? You could use the data tag of html5 in conjuction with .data() of jquery, search the documentation on this. And yes, it is possible to make a drop down in the radio, just be creative =D

Answer (score 1):

You need to hide the div wrapping the unchecked radio elements. Then you don't have to worry about the labels because they are inside the parent div as well.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpeYod

```
var hid = false;

$("group.inline-radio").click(function() {
  if (hid == false) {

    $('group.inline-radio').find('input[type="radio"]').not(':checked').parent().hide();

    hid = true;
    return;
  } else {
    $('group.inline-radio').find('input[type="radio"]').not(':checked').parent().show();

    hid = false;
  }

});
```

Also, unless you want the selected div to fill the entire  element then you need set specific widths on them.